# Voltage/resistors/series/impedance/meter

Tags: voltage, resistors, impedance, series, meter

Assume you measure a power supply voltage through a series 1M OHM resistor and observe that is drops by 1/2 its former value when no resistor is in series. What is the input impedance of the meter? Explain your answer.

Comment: This smells an *awful* lot like homework to me...

Comment: -1 for dumping a homework problem on us and just expecting us to answer.  We'll help with theory or particular points of confusion, but just giving you the answer defeats the purpose of the exercise.

Comment: If you actually want to learn, draw out the circuit and show us the result, then explain what specifically you are stuck on.  If you don't to learn, go away, that's not what we are here for.

Comment: Depends on the output impedance of the power supply which is unknown, so it is impossible to answer.

Comment: @jippie: I think that since "power supply" was specifically mentioned, we are expected to make the assumption that its output impedance is much much less than 1 MOhm, as would be true with just about anything called a "power supply".  In other words, I think it's obvious in this case that "power supply" is meant to be interpreted as "voltage source".

Comment: @OlinLathrop I am usually very bad at guessing under these given circumstances ;o)

Answer (score 2):

1Meg ohm.  Voltage divider: output=input(R1/(R1+R2))  You've got the 1M of the meter being the R1 and R2 is the external series R.  1/1+1 or 0.5 of your input is the output voltage.

Comment: -1 of outright answering a homework problem.

Comment: Sorry, rushed it w/o thinking.

Comment: +1 to counter -1 for answering hw problem.  Although I don't think it right to answer hw completely, I think that a comment suffices, rather than downvoting.

Comment: Agreed with anorton (though I wont upvote). Downvotes should be used to indicate incorrect answers, not forward personal agendas.

Comment: @OlinLathrop we should not give lower quality answers or worse, ignore questions entirely just because we **assume** that they are homework (remember, nobody ever said that it was, it is all in your head). Letting your hatred for bad questions bleed over into the answers given is just outrageous. This answer, correct or not, was given innocently and doesn't deserve to be punished just because the question was not up to standards.